# Paypal(PHP): unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal

I'm using Paypal Express Checkout for my shopping chart. i have created my API certificate file as below.
[image]

i have downloaed the api certificate file `cert_key_pem.txt` and used for api credential as below.

```
  $API_UserName = $paypal->username;
  $API_Password = $paypal->password;
  $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp";
  $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
  $version="64";
  $currencyCodeType = "USD";
  $paymentType = "Sale";
  $methodName = "DoExpressCheckoutPayment";
  $certFile = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\project-name\cert_key.txt';//forlocalhost
  //$certFile = '/home/cpanel-username/public_html/cert_key_pem.txt'; //for live server

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $certFile);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  $nvpreq="METHOD=" . urlencode($methodName) . "&VERSION=" . urlencode($version) . "&PWD=" . urlencode($API_Password) . "&USER=" . urlencode($API_UserName) . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
  {
     $message = curl_error($ch);
  }
  else
  {
     $message = 'Operation completed without any errors';
  }

 curl_close($ch);

 echo $message;
```

but i got the error message as below.

```
  unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)
```

if you have any idea on solving such type of errors then please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using certificate to auth the API, you may want to change the endpoint to https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp

The https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp, and all "-3t" surffixed endpoints are for signature auth API calls (3T means 3 token: username/password/signature)